# Review page doesn't show unicode(!?) characters properly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I noticed this on Web Apps First Post Review queue - [from the review queue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/7316), this is how the post looks like:

[image]

From the [main question screen](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35795/cannot-copy-text-from-pdf-generated-with-google-docs), this is how the page looks like:

[image]

So the review page doesn't seem to be show those unicode(!?) characters. Please note that this isn't about the characters showing up as boxes, it's about the characters not appearing at all on the review page.

Comment: Looks like the queue view might filter invalid characters? Not sure

Comment: Just to note I copy pasted these into word and switched to a unicode capable font. My guess is these things are some odd, embedded, non standard font.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: That looks like encoded data instead; there is a repeating pattern in the bytes, as would be used by a multi-byte encoding. Decoding from UTF8 puts them all in the `<Plane 16 PRivate Use>` area, so that is probably incorrect. I doubt they are actual characters *as is* though.

Answer (score 4):

This is a JSON encoding bug in the library we're using for... basically everything JSON.

<del>A patch has been submitted, we should be pulling in an updated version soon-ish.</del>

We'll be pushing out a new dll with the next build.